# Custom variables do not work with setq in emacs

Tags: variables, emacs, customization

Okay, so I am fairly new to emacs and even newer to lisps. So I know that we can set variable values by this:

```
(setq variable value)
```

However, there seem to be some variables which don't seem to work when set with setq. For example: **markdown-hide-markup** in the markdown-mode package. They do work if they are set through **customize** UI, or by doing it the following way:

```
(custom-set-variables 
 '(markdown-enable-wiki-links t)
 '(markdown-enable-math t)
 '(markdown-hide-markup t)
 '(markdown-fontify-code-blocks-natively t)
)
```

So well, I just wanted to know if I am missing something? Or is there a better way to do it or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user option (i.e., a variable defined by `defcustom`) has a default value, some allowable values, and ways of initializing, setting, and getting it.

The default way of setting it is essentially `setq-default`, which is like `setq` but if the variable has buffer-local values it sets the default (global) value.

But if the `defcustom` defines a specific setter function then you need to use a Customize function to set the value, as you discovered (or use the Customize UI, which is always a good idea). This is the case if the `defcustom` has a (non-default) specification of **`:set`**.

If you use `custom-set-variables` or `customize-set-variable` instead of `setq` (or `setq-default`), or if you use the Customize user interface (e.g. `M-x customize-option`), then you are sure that any intended initialization or updating (setting) code that is needed for the option value will be automatically triggered and run as needed. If you use `setq`, this will not be done.

See also this emacs.StackExchange [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/106/105).

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful. I would just like to ask that is it really better to use customize UI? Coz it seems even if we specify a separate file like given in the post, it still will be messy when your Emacs config gets extremely long and you need to specify a lot of custom variables. For example for someone using exwm

Comment: I never use it - but you should understand the problems that can occur.  99% of the time it doesn't matter if you use setq - but for special cases, eg. keymap prefixes that need to be recomputed after changing the prefix, you need to set the prefix before loading the package, or use the setter function `(funcall (get '<var> 'custom-set) '<var> <value>)`

Comment: the main thing - it you use `setq` before loading the package, you probably won't ever run into problems, unless you change variables on-the-fly